# Unable to debug Keycloak from latest (7.0.1) docker image

Tags: java, docker, debugging, keycloak

Since the latest (7.0.1) docker image, it's no more possible to connect a remote debug session to the JVM running within the container.

I've launched :

```
docker run \
  -p 9001:8080 \
  -p 9100:9100 \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password \
  jboss/keycloak:7.0.1 \
  -b 0.0.0.0 \
  --debug 9100
```

and then try to connect a debug session with this VSCode configuration:

```
{
"type": "java",
"name": "Debug (Attach) - Remote",
"request": "attach",
"hostName": "localhost",
"port": 9100
}
```

and got the following message:

```
Failed to attach to remote debuggee VM
Reason:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

BTW, the same works fine with Keycloak with 6.0.1 and 7.0.0 docker images.

I suspect this is a side effect of the move to the new ubi8-minimal base image used since Keycloak 7.0.1

Any clue about how to solve this issue ?

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is Java update: 8 (Keycloak 7.0.0) vs. 11 (Keycloak 7.0.1). Java 9+ listens only on localhost by default, so could you try to listen on all interfaces (`*:9100`):

```
docker run \
  -p 9001:8080 \
  -p 9100:9100 \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password \
  jboss/keycloak:7.0.1 \
  -b 0.0.0.0 \
  --debug *:9100
```

Comment: How can I connect using remote configuration in IntelliJ?

Comment: For Keycloak v 7.0.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593731/4539906

Comment: @AsadShakeel If you start your standalone in debug mode (or docker), click on attach debug process, automatically jboss listenable ports witll be listed.