# How to remote debug attach Keycloak in versions > 8

Tags: debugging, keycloak

I recently upgraded Keycloak to version 9, and when running in Docker, I'm having trouble attaching a remote debugger.  I suspect this has to do with Keycloak's underlying upgrade to Java 9+.

The error I get is:

`handshake failed - connection prematurally closed`

I have my ports mapped correctly within Docker (I can run Keycloak version 7 and it attaches just fine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, Java 9 introduced a security enhancement with respect to debugging.  Information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60090750/2117355

In my Keycloak docker-compose service definition, I was able to add under `environment`:

`DEBUG_PORT: "*:8787"`

And that fixed the problem.  I'm now able to debug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that at least from 11.0.2 onwards, you'll need to set the environment variable `DEBUG: "true"` also.

Answer (score 9):

The approach depends on whether you're using `standalone.sh` (or .bat presumably) or a docker image.

If you're using `standalone.sh`, you can use the `--debug` option, documented in `standalone.sh -h`:

```
standalone.sh --debug '*:8000'
```

(the `*` is to allow access from any host. Plain `--debug 8000` will allow access only from localhost)

For docker images, this will be the [documented](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) approach [from version 12](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/pull/306) on, and it works at least from Keycloak 11.0.2:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/docker-compose/keycloak-standalone/docker-compose.yml b/docker-compose/keycloak-standalone/docker-compose.yml
index fcf3a52..93b7209 100644
--- a/docker-compose/keycloak-standalone/docker-compose.yml
+++ b/docker-compose/keycloak-standalone/docker-compose.yml
@@ -11,11 +11,14 @@ services:
       environment:
         KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
         KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
+        DEBUG: "true"
+        DEBUG_PORT: "*:8000"
       ports:
         - 8080:8080
+        - 8000:8000
       volumes:
         - data:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data
```

(Again, the `*` is to allow access from any host.)

Comment: This is the approach that will be documented from version 12 onwards. See [KEYCLOAK-16506 README: docker envs for Java debugger by pmorch · Pull Request #306 · keycloak/keycloak-containers](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/pull/306)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace debug params by creating your own image, using Dockerfile

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest
ENV DEBUG true
ENV DEBUG_PORT *:8787
EXPOSE 8080 8443 9990 8787
ENTRYPOINT ${JBOSS_HOME}/../tools/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

**console:**

```
docker build -t local/debug-keycloack ..
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 -p 9990:9990 -p 8787:8787 --name debug-keycloack local/debug-keycloack
```

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch it's just an option. A different way to enable remote debug

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is not related to docker, just trying to help anyone who needs this**

For keycloak 22.0.1, I use intellij to debug my custom SPI (which I put in /provider as a jar file), then start keycloak locally, and do remote debug.

1. Run `kc.bat start-dev --http-relative-path=/auth --debug`inside`C:\YourPath\keycloak-22.0.1\bin>`, it will then show something like `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 63506`
2. Open intellij, Ctrl+Alt+F5 to open `attach to process` (Or Run | Attach to Process), choose the address, for example `63506`
3. Then you can do your remote debugging! Start by setting some breakpoints and open `localhost:8080` and do your stuff

Comment: Since this doesn't directly answer the question - it might be more suited as a comment

Answer (score 0):

**For Keycloak version 7**

I'm using this command to run the docker container to enable debugging at port `1234`

```
docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin 
-e JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m 
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman 
   -Djava.awt.headless=true 
   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=1234,server=y,suspend=n" 
-p 8080:8080 -p 1234:1234 jboss/keycloak:7.0.0
```

Connecting it to the IntelliJ using Remote Configuration

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1234`

***Note:** The default value of the `JAVA_OPTS` is below so I prepended it with the above configuration

```
-server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m 
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman 
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Comment: Adding `DEFAULT_MODULAR_JVM_OPTIONS` will be better instead of updating `JAVA_OPTS` .

`-e DEFAULT_MODULAR_JVM_OPTIONS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"`